# The Python Games that come with NOOBS extend off screen

Tags: pi-3, python, touchscreen

Most (all?) Python games that come with NOOBS (Pentamino, GemGem etc) extend off the bottom of my Raspberry Pi 7-inch touch screen.  I can successfully play some of them by right clicking the TLH corner and moving the window up, but this is not always enough.

I have read about under and over scan in the User Guide. Is this the anser? I am very hesitant because the desktop fits perfectly.